# Where do I go to enable search in Sharepoint 2007?

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I am modifying an existing Sharepoint 2007 site. It just has two pages, the home page, and an admin page. The admin page has a couple form/document libraries. I simply want to have a search so that a user can search through all the documents/forms in the document/form library. I dont care if its a whole site search, as long as it pulls up results including those from all the document/form libraries on the site.

I have enabled site visibility ("allow this web to appear in search results") on both pages. I just cant find anywhere to enable an actual search button/search textbox/search webpart. I just want the actual control where i can type in a word and hit search. where/how can I enable that?

When I go to sharepoint designer I can see the search box at the top of the master page, but cant see it on the published (live) page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently a previous developer had modified the master page to hide the search feature controls.

The line in my master page that I had to edit was:

```
<td valign=top>
          <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderSearchArea" runat="server">
                <SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" ControlId="SmallSearchInputBox"/>
          </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</td>
```

The table cell had an inline style to "display:none;" which I removed.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, search in MOSS 2007 is a BIG deal to understand... don't expect button "On/Off"!

Now that this is clear:

When you watch master page in sharepoint designer, you are seeing a page template as it would be seen with all functions enabled. So master page has to have the search button inside, so that MOSS knows where to show search button when it is enabled.

As for the first question:

1. First check in your server in the Central Administration Home page > if you have enabled search, crawling (to have any results in the first place) etc...
2. On your main site collection go to: "Site Actions > Site Settings > Modify All Site Settings > Site Collection Administration > Search settings" and check if you have enabled site search page.
3. Edit your search scopes.

P.S. Also I'm using a book for this kind of settings - great book
Office Sharepoint server 2007 - Administrator's companion
from Microsoft, written by Bill English (MS Sharepoint Community Expert)